# how to remove a row in radgridview?

Tags: winforms, telerik, delete-row, radgridview

//   i edit a row on radgridview

```
   radgridview.rows[0].value = true;
```

//   then i can not delete it.

```
    radgridview.rows[0].delete();
```

//    if i try delete that row got the this exception => cannot remove objects not in the list

//   but if i don't edit that row so i can delete it.

//   plz help ,how to solved this problem?

Comment: hi. what which radcontrols are you using - ASP.NET AJAX/WPF ???

Comment: my radcontrol is radgridview this is WINFORM control

Comment: why bother to edit it, if you're going to delete it? Anyway, you cannot delete because of rowstate. Call an Acceptchanges, then delete

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a row values using this code:

```
radgridview.rows[0].value = true;
```

The correct code will be:

```
radGridView1.Rows[0].Cells["Your column name"].Value = true;
```

As to your question about deleting a row, if the grid is data bound to a simple List you can delete the row by deleting it straight from the list and Updating the grid. Alternatively, to handle all notifications properly, the collection that you bind to should implement the **IBindingList** interface (you can use **BindingList**) and your object stored in the collection should implement the **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface.

If this is not the case, let us know what exactly is your binding scenario.